# Is there a way to make the icons in Geany IDE brighter?

Tags: icons, gtk, color-scheme, geany, xfce

I'm using the Geany IDE with the GTK3 theme set to Adwaita-Dark. For the most part this works perfectly fine. However, the icons at the top screen are too dark to see clearly:[image: Screenshot of Geany]
Is it possible to change these icons to make them more visible against the dark background? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. If anyone else is in a similar situation I used the Xfce appearance settings (I'm using Manjaro Linux). In retrospect it was a little illogical to be searching for solutions using the GTK settings when I have an Xfce desktop, but now I know.